# validation of email with specific domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, email

*This coding on separate page works fine. but if i included in below form not working*

```html
<html>


<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="signup" method="post">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail." />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>




<script type="text/javascript">


$('#signup').submit(function() {
    validateEmail($('input').val());
    return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@metronet.in', email.length - '@metronet.in'.length) !== -1) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
        } else {
            alert('Email must be a CE e-mail address (your.name@metronet.in).');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
    }
}

</script>


<!--Load JQuery-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/metismenu/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/blockui-master/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/blockui-master/js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>


    
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>



<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

*i have an registration page where  all fields are entered,it should check whether email id column should contain @c-e.com domain,if user entered abcd@c-e.com it should proceed or else should pop up a message like need to enter c-e.com domain name,for that i have written a script but for all email id's it is displaying message like not an valid email address.none of the part works.If i paste same code with form of email ,submit button alone in other page,it pops up message ,but in this register.php not works*

```html
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
 header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
 $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
 $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
 
 //name can contain only alpha characters and space
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
  $error = true;
  $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
 }
 if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $error = true;
  $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
 }
 if(strlen($password) < 6) {
  $error = true;
  $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
 }
 if($password != $cpassword) {
  $error = true;
  $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
 }
 if (!$error) {
  if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
   $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
  } else {
   $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
  }
 }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>User Registration Script</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>
</br></br>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
   <form role="form" id="signup" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Sign Up</legend>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required value="<?php if($error) echo $name; ?>" class="form-control" />
      <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span>
     </div>
     
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required value="<?php if($error) echo $email; ?>" class="form-control" />
      <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control" />
      <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error; ?></span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required class="form-control" />
      <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($cpassword_error)) echo $cpassword_error; ?></span>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary" />
     </div>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   <span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($successmsg)) { echo $successmsg; } ?></span>
   <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center"> 
  Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login Here</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">


$('#signup').submit(function() {
    validateEmail($('input').val());
    return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@c-e.com', email.length - '@c-e.com'.length) !== -1) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
        } else {
            alert('Email must be a CE e-mail address (your.name@c-e.com).');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
    }
}



</script>







<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wan't to explode the email and check if it contain what you want like this,

```
$explode = explode("@", $email);
if($explode[1] == 'c-e.com'){
    //Email is valid 
}else{
    //Email is not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following way :

```
function validateEmail($email)
{
  // Check E-mail address is valid
  if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $email)) return false;
 // Check for specific domain(s)
  $SpecificDomains = array('c-e.com','gmail.com','example.com');
  list(, $email_domain) = explode('@', $email, 2);
  return !in_array($email_domain, $SpecificDomains);
}
```

Comment: without validating @c-e.com it is registering in dbs.no error msg

Comment: i have added an code,juz chk it that ,it works. but if i  combined a form in separate page ,no use